# Assigning SQL Statement to Class Variable

Tags: php, class, pdo

I stated to build up my Database Class.

Here is a part of my database class.

```
public function query($sql)
{
   return $this->getPdo()->query($sql);
}
```

My Class is working but i want to improve it.

This is external part of class:

```
$db = new Database();
$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');

while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $r;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

I want to get while part inside database class like

```
public function query($sql)
{
   return $this->getPdo()->query($sql);
}

public function getAll() {
    while($r = $this->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[] = $r;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

But i know this part is wrong : $this->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); How can i fix it ? I have to declare a class varible like $sql, and i have to assign sql statement to $sql varible.

But i couldn't. How can i do that ?

Comment: Do you have **prepared statements** support in your class?

Comment: now there isn't. But i'll added it. Binding values and preparing is more complex for me now. After i solve this issue. I'll do that. But step by step.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$results = $q->fetchAll();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your biggest problems is that when you write

```
public function getAll() {
    while($r = $this->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[] = $r;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

you are causing the database to run the query with each iteration of the loop.

To correct the code as it is defined simply run the query outside of the loop then use fetch as the loop condition:

```
public function getAll() {
    $stmt = $this->query($sql);
    while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[] = $r;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Another problem that is probably probably causing you grief is that the $sql value appears to be coming from out of thin air.  You should pass it into your getAll function to have access to it.

To avoid all this noise you might want to just follow @YourCommonSense's suggestion and use the available PDO getAll method.

```
 public function getAll($sql){
      return $this->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass the `$sql` parameter to your `getAll()` method, and then use `return` to get the result back out.  So this method becomes:

```
public function getAll($sql) {
    while($r = $this->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $results[] = $r;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Then you use it externally like:

```
$db = new Database();
$results = $db->getAll('SELECT * FROM table');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
```